# Rename files in a batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch, rename

I want to rename `file1` to `file2` using a batch file in Windows 7 but with no luck.

Below is the batch file:

```
@echo off
c:
cd\test
ren file1 file2
```

Error message I get is

```
syntax error.
```

---

Update to my question:
However, to be more specific, the following is the content of my script named update.cmd which I will run as administrator in Windows 7.

Here it is:

```
:START
cls
cd C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit Structure 2012\Program
ren C:RevitMFC.dll RevitMFC_dll.bak
```

When I cross check the program lines above using cmd.exe run as administrator, I found out the error msg is "access is denied".

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Ben>cd c:\program files\autodesk\revit structure 2012\program

c:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit Structure 2012\Program>ren c:revitmfc.dll revitm fc_dll.bak Access is denied.

c:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit Structure 2012\Program>
```

My question: How do I overcome this "Access is denied" ?

Comment: @slhck, actually, that **does** work. Try it!

Comment: @BenBever, there is nothing wrong with the syntax you entered in the question, so you may have fixed it while typing the question. Check the actual `.bat` file to make sure there isn't a syntax error.

Comment: @Synetech Well, learned something new then ;)

Comment: Generally, you can do this sort of thing so long as the character right after the command name is a delimiter (e.g. `cd\progra~1`, `dir/s/o/a/p`, `foobar/?`), but not always (e.g., `attrib+r+a+s+h a.txt` won't work).

Comment: @Synetech: Since DOS 3.0, spaces after a command are optional if the following character is a `/`, ``\`` or `.`. I still get `command not found` every once in a while for executing `cd..` in `bash`...

Comment: @Dennis *> Since DOS 3.0, spaces after a command are optional if the following character is a /, \ or .*   Ah, nice to know. Is there a reference or list of other details for that?     *> I still get command not found every once in a while for executing cd.. in bash*  Hehe, I love `cd..` (and loved `cd...`, `cd....`, etc.) `:-)`

Comment: @Synetech: I consulted [MS-DOS Mühelos!](http://www.amazon.de/m%C3%BChelos-garantiert-fr%C3%B6hlicher-Cartoon-Computer/dp/3893904301) (German: *MS-DOS without effort*). It's from 1989 and it hasn't been translated to English. I learned DOS with the help of that book and its sequel: [Batchman](http://www.amazon.de/Batchman-Fortsetzung-MS-DOSe-versch%C3%A4rften-Mitteln/dp/3893903291/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1339118060&sr=1-1).

Comment: @Dennis, ah, interesting. I have a copy of a couple of old DOS programming texts and my (tall, skinny) DOS 3.3 manuals from my Tandy. I’m tempted to find them and check if they have these kinds of details. Who know’s what forgotten secrets they could contain.

Comment: Learn to format your posts, please. You can indent code with `Ctrl-K`, or by adding 4 spaces to each line.

Comment: Dennis is correct; the syntax error(s) you got are because the filenames have spaces. You need to wrap the filenames in quotes: `cd "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit Structure 2012\Program"`, `ren "foo bar.txt" "blah bloo.txt"`

Comment: As for the access problem, do you get an access/permission prompt when you rename them in Explorer and have to click `Continue`?

Answer (score 3):

If

```
ren file1 file2
```

gives a syntax error, there are most certainly spaces in the files' names.

Try this instead:

```
ren "file1" "file2"
```

Comment: If Dennis is correct (and probably is), then the actual error message is `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a `\` after the `CD` command.

Try this:

```
@echo off
c:
cd test
ren file1 file2
```

Comment: You could even shorten it up by removing the `c:` & `cd test` and simply give the command on one line with the path like this: 
`ren c:\test\file1 file2`

Comment: Why not? It works. Try it!

Comment: @Synetech You're right. In all my years I have never used it. So it looked odd to me. Thanks for pointing that out. I think Dennis is on the right thought path now.

Comment: yes, there's all these weird things we keep noticing. There were a couple I found out about in the past year or two. Check my comment to the main question for details about this.

Comment: To be more specific, the following is the content of my script named update.cmd which I will run as administrator in Windows 7.

Here it is:
------------------------------------------------------------
:START
cls

cd C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit Structure 2012\Program
ren C:RevitMFC.dll RevitMFC_dll.bak
------------------------------------------------------------

I cross check the program lines using cmd.exe rus as administrator and I found out the error msg is access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting the "Access Denied" error because the file or folder is read only. The other possibility is the file is in use.

You can check the file attributes as follows. To check the folder's attributes leave out the file name.

```
attrib  [[Drive:][Path] FileName]
```

[Here](http://www.computerhope.com/attribhl.htm) is more info on how to use the **attrib** command.

In order to rename the file with your batch file, you will need to modify the attributes of the file, and possibly the folder. After renaming the file change the attributes back.

**Word of warning;** changing the name of a dynamic link library (dll) file can cause the program(s) it is associated with to stop working.

Comment: The file or folder is not marked read only. I can change the file name using Explorer but not using the script I intend to use.