# How do I rename multiple files on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, rename, batch-rename

I have 2800 files, all of whose names start with a four-digit number followed by " - ", and I want to delete all those leading numbers from all the files, leaving only the alphanumeric file names<sup>1</sup>. 
How can I do this?
________________
<sup>1</sup> Some of the filenames contain numerals after the " - ".

[image]

Comment: Yes, you could write a batch script. The fact this question has been asked before shows you've done no research. Can you share the script you've tried to write?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I mass rename files?](http://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files) OR http://superuser.com/questions/434014/rename-files-in-a-batch-file OR http://superuser.com/questions/671270/how-to-optionally-copy-and-rename-a-file-in-windows

Comment: Thanks for not deluging us with all 2800 filenames.  Even so, you gave us four or five times more than you needed to (i.e., eight to ten illustrative examples would have been plenty).  And, in the future, when you have purely textual information (like a list of filenames) that you want to include in a question (or an answer), try to post it *as text* rather than an image.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell!  Something like this should do what you want it to do.  It will take teh first 7 characters off of the file name and rename it (7 characters is 4 digit number + 1 space + 1 hyphen + 1 space)

This relies on you having a definite pattern of "0000 - " before the filename and won't play nicely if it results in duplicate file names, but is a good jumping off point.

`Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "D:\bigfolderofstuff\" | ForEach {
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name).Substring(7)
}`

Comment: +1 for warning that truncation of filenames may result in duplication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running windows,
In the past when I encounter similar problems I have used "Batch renaming tool" with considerable success.

Can be downloaded here, it is free and it works:

http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php